# Installing Ruby Passenger is like Rolling the Dice. I'm getting an internal server error and it just looks like nothing is working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache2, passenger, internal

I'm just going through the basic tutorial and then installing passenger.  I got all of this working once before.  I'm following the instructions on the passenger site word for word and now I have an internal server error.  I really like ruby on rails, but every time I install the whole stack of ruby / rails / passenger etc.. it seems like there are too many bits that can go wrong.  Here is my current apache error log.  If anyone can help me I would really appreciate it and maybe we can make this process easier for the next guy. Thank you!

```
[Sun Apr 28 19:32:53 2013] [error] [client 66.249.76.209] Premature end of script headers: lib
[ pid=25147 thr=139705268700928 file=ext/apache2/Hooks.cpp:841 time=2013-04-28 19:32:53.191 ]: The backend application (process 26074) did not send a valid HTTP response; instead, it sent nothing at all. It is possible that it has crashed; please check whether there are crashing bugs in this application.
[ pid=26074 thr=16544380 file=utils.rb:176 time=2013-04-28 19:32:53.191 ]: *** Exception Psych::SyntaxError in application (couldn't parse YAML at line 39 column 10) (process 26074, thread #<Thread:0x00000001f8e4f8>):
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:148:in `parse'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:148:in `parse_stream'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:119:in `parse'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:106:in `load'
@
```

.....lots more...
...then....

```
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/passenger-3.0.19/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:246:in `block in spawn_rack_application' 
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/passenger-3.0.19/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:82:in `block in synchronize' 
        from <internal:prelude>:10:in `synchronize' 
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/passenger-3.0.19/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:79:in `synchronize' 
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/passenger-3.0.19/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:244:in `spawn_rack_application' 
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/passenger-3.0.19/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:137:in `spawn_application' 
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/passenger-3.0.19/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:275:in `handle_spawn_application' 
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/passenger-3.0.19/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `server_main_loop' 
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/passenger-3.0.19/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:206:in `start_synchronously' 
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/passenger-3.0.19/helper-scripts/passenger-spawn-server:99:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0):

That looks like an application error. You should post the full stack trace.